# Can you configure Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 to ignore the domain being used from internet and to just use a local domain?

Tags: active-directory, domain, exchange-2007

Is this even possible to configure Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 to ignore the chosen domain on the internet and just to utilize the domain locally?  Or is this totally not in context of what Exchange Server is meant to do?  Thanks...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I can't figure out at all what this question is actually asking.  Please clarify.

Comment: If you are trying to use Exchange for Intranet communications only and not Internet, then I think the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes @USACASD, that is pretty much what I am looking for.  Thanks.  Any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O_O, just remove it as an accecpted domain under Organization Configuration>Hub Transport>Accepted Domains. This only affects SMTP addresses, and it will still use X.400 to route internally.

Comment: Hi KCotreau, Where can I find the organization configuration window?  Thanks!!

Comment: It is in the Exchange Management Console. It will be at the top left.

Comment: Hi again, I have a question and hope you could help explain to me if possible.  Is this equivalent to just deploying a client access server, hub transport, and mailbox server without the edge transport server? Or do you really need to remove the domain from the accepted domains?  Thank you very much for your guidance.

Comment: The edge transport server is a separate server that you put on a DMZ for security perposes...to separate the client access part from the more critical data part: Are you using two servers? Personally, I have never seen a situation where you would not want mail coming in from the Internet, so I have never removed the only accepted domain, but you asked how to make it only work internally, so I told you one way.